# Selenium Python; Using xpath, find_element successfully finds the first element, but find_elements returning an empty set, path unchanged

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm very new to Selenium so sorry if I've missed a core step somehow. Here's my code:

By this point it has navigated to a person's Twitter profile and wants to collect all the tweet "cards" that have loaded so far.

```
cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')
print(cards)
>>>[]
```

But strangely,

```
card = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')
print(card.text)
```

does correctly return all of the text in the very first tweet on the profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print this `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')))` and let us know the size of the list.

Also `print(cards)` would print `hex code` of the `web elements.` not the text on them.

also iterate like this :

```
cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')
for card in cards:
   print(card.text)
```

or

```
cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')
  for card in cards:
     print(card.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Update :**

`find_elements` works on a principle of `implciit waits`, `driver.implicitly_wait(50)` put that after you **initialize the browser.** –

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I ran the len() as you said and it returns 0 again. Also, I've tried the for loop too and since it's returning an empty set pretty much the same happens again.

Comment: then `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')` should not work either. try to put some sleep, like `time.sleep(5)` before extracting the data.

Comment: I've made sure several times that I'm not messing up any syntax, and find_element does return the hex value of the tweet while find_elements just returns the empty set as I mentioned above. And yes I've made sure to wait until the page is fully loaded.

Comment: find_elements works on a principle of implciit waits, `driver.implicitly_wait(50)` put that after you initialize the browser.